# TYPO3 9.5 LTS - configuration for custom PAGE type with routeEnhancers

Tags: typo3, vcf-vcard, typenum

I have a vCard-solution that worked fine with TYPO3 version 8 and realURL but doesn't work with TYPO3 9.5.

vCard is triggered with an URL like:
mywebsite.de/de/vcard.html?staffid=123&type=5000

Configuration:

1) staffid=123 loads the values of staff member with ID 123 into the vCard:

```
[globalVar = GP:staffid=123]
  VCARD_name = vcard-schneider-martin.vcf
  N_name = N:Schneider;Martin;;;Martin Schneider
  [...]
[global]
```

2) in order to load the special PAGE type the TypoScript is:

```
vCard = PAGE
vCard {
  typeNum = 5000

  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/x-vcard|Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="{$VCARD_name}"
    [...]
  }
}
```

How does the routeEnhancers (of config.yaml) has to be configured in order to make TYPO3 9.5 starting the vCard PAGE object with typeNum=5000 and render the vCard for the team member with the current value of GP variable "staffid" (from the URL)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this configuration for sitemap.xml with pageType 1533906435 and backslash für pageType 0 (section map of my config):

```
routeEnhancers:
    PageTypeSuffix:
        type: PageType
        default: /
        index: ''
        map:
            /: 0
            sitemap.xml: 1533906435
```

see also:
https://usetypo3.com/xml-sitemap-in-typo3.html

Comment: Thank you, Andreas.
However I do not have a special document type like .xml or .json. 
I need a routeEnhancer configuration that informs TYPO3 about the GP-variable staffid and about the special document type so it renders the vCard instead of loading a standard HTML page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Then the map-config should be:
vcard.html: 5000
What is output then depends on the parameter "staffid".

Comment: Andreas: thanks!
I have already tested out map:vcard.html but it didn't work. Have made some changes on the whole config.yaml in the meantime. After re-testing your suggested solution it suddenly worked out.